# pouchdb.query is taking more time

Tags: cordova, pouchdb

I am having around 50 documents in my pouch DB. I am querying the database while angular service is loading. I know that we can use **alldocs** method which is pretty much faster than query method. But in my case **allDocs** is not sufficient why because Each and every document will have lastUpdatedTime in milliseconds. Based on the lastUpdatedTime I will query the DB to get fresh records sort by lastUpdatedTime. But alldocs method doesn't have option to sort the documents based on document filed value. My doc design is something like this `var byTimestampDoc = this.createDesignDoc('by_timestamp', function (doc) {
            if (doc.objType == "message") {
                emit(doc.lastUpdated);
            }
        });
db.put(byTimestampDoc)`

---

Right now query is taking about 9781.726ms to return the rows while loading the app in Android but in iOS it taking less than 3 seconds . Can anyone help me to improve the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know which documents were most recently updated, you can actually use the built-in `changes()` API ([docs here](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#changes)), which is just as fast as `allDocs()`.

Queries tend to be slow because 1) the `map()` function has to run for *every single document in your database* (e.g. documents whose `objType` isn't `'message'`,), and 2) it only updates at the moment you `query()` it.

So if you have a database with frequently-changing documents, each `query()` is reading through every changed document since you last `query()`d it, which is why it's slow.

Comment: If I use allDocs method to get the records into in my controller and then after that if I do sorting those records programmatically based on lastUpdatedTime will it have any performance issue than query(). If I load records by using allDocs from my controller it is taking less time. But the same code if I put inside service which is taking time.

Comment: If you do the sorting in-memory, then you are reading in the entire database just to sort it. That can be faster if your data is constantly changing, but in that case I would ask if it makes sense to use PouchDB, or if you should instead just keep all your objects in-memory and then save them as one big JSON blob to LocalForage. Might make more sense.

Comment: To answer your question more directly, the _first_ `query()` is slowest because it has to build up the data and write it to disk, but the second time it should be faster. I say "should" because if the data is constantly changing, then it will have to rebuild.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also try the PouchDB in-memory adapter and then just occasionally dump your database to IndexedDB using `pouchdb-replication-stream` or using regular replication between the in-memory database and the IndexedDB database.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and in-depth explanation. I will give a try with PouchDB in memory adapter.